# Какой падеж нужен - родительный или винительный?

Tags: падежи, родительный-или-винительный

Здравствуйте!

Скажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сказать: "В случае, если ... не предоставит необходимые входные данные" или "... не предоставит необходимых входных данных", т.е. родительный или винительный падеж надо использовать?

Answer (score 1):

ПРАВИЛО

При переходных глаголах с отрицанием может использоваться дополнение как в Р.п., так и  в В.п.

Они различаются следующим образом:

1) Родительный падеж подчеркивает отрицание, а винительный - ослабляет его. 
2) Родительный падеж характерен для книжной речи, в винительный - для разговорной.
3) Также есть большое количество формальных признаков, влияющих на выбор падежа, в частности семантика глагола.

РЕШЕНИЕ

С одной стороны, мы имеем книжный деловой стиль, где следует использовать Р.п. Кроме того, выбор Р.п. характерен для глаголов  "иметь, получать, доставать и др.", которые всегда обозначают полное отрицание. С другой стороны, на выбор В.п. может повлиять конкретное значение существительного, а также совершенный вид глагола (результативность действия).

В результате мы видим использование обоих вариантов: (1)Газпром пока не предоставляет такую информацию в полном объеме. ― (2)Сегодня российское законодательство ни органам государственной власти, ни местного самоуправления не предоставляет права.

При сравнении двух вариантов можно сделать вывод, что при вещественном  значении существительных лучше использовать В.п., а при  отвлеченном значении - Р.п.

Таким образом, в приведенном примере предлагается использовать В.п.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо вам большое за быстрый и подробный ответ на мои вопросы.